# passing a global variable to a closure

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I'm trying to implement sorting based on action sheet choice, where the sorting happens in the handler, but I can't pass the array i want to sort to the handler. Here is my code:

```
let byWage = UIAlertAction(title: "By Wage", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
  unclaimedJobs.sort() { $0.wage > $1.wage }
})
```

where `unclaimedJobs` is a global variable. What's the best way to do this?

Edit: This where I declare `unclaimedJobs` :

```
class JobsListViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

   var jobsList: JobsList!
   var unclaimedJobs: [Job]!
```

I initialize it in `viewDidLoad()`.

Edit#2: I understand you need a `UIAlertAction` to be passed to the closure, so I replaced `(unclaimedJobs)` with `action.`

Last Edit: I fixed this by putting `self.unclaimedJobs` instead of `unclaimedJobs.`

Comment: Can you add the code and context in which `unclaimedJobs` is declared ?

Comment: I'll edit my question!

Comment: Just to clarify, in the code you posted, `unclaimedJobs` isn't a global variable; it's a property of `JobsListViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to an object inside a closure, you need an explicit reference to it. In your case it's probably - self: like in self.unclaimedJobs. However, you have to unown this object like [unowned self] inside the closure, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Doesn't Swift take care of that? If not, how would I do that using Swift?

Comment: This works in Swift like this: { [unowned self] in ...code... }

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure. But I think it's this.

```
let byWage = UIAlertAction(title: "By Wage", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in unclaimedJobs.sort({$0 > $1}) })
```

Comment: the problem is, it doesn't seem to know what unclaimedJobs is.

Comment: Can you post your `viewDidLoad()`. I am not understanding why we are referencing the class variable directly